# Can I install IIS7 and get localhost working on my home computer

Tags: windows, iis

Currently have installed Windows 7 Home premium, im just wondering if i can install IIS7 on this and work on some apps on my home computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Home Premium, Home Basic, or Home Starter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx).  Not sure if that's what you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use IIS Express available for free at asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can (IIS 7.5), but for your home PC I would suggest using IIS Express instead.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Comment: Just a quick question I managed to get IIS by just enabling the windows feature through control panel, and it looks like its there now. Is there any difference in doing that and downloading via the link you posted?

Comment: Well the Windows Feature should have installed 7.5 Full while the link I provided is to Express.